# How to handle external C# code runtime compilation

Tags: c#, compilation, runtime

I want to have the possibility to runtime compile code coming from an external file.
I started from [this](https://riptutorial.com/csharp/example/10702/csharpcodeprovider#google_vignette) and that works

From that I wanted to make a little more complicated by adding the possibility to pass:

1. an external parameter as a string
2. external source code which I read from a file.

This is the code

```
public static string CreateCSharpFunction(string strCode, string strPar1 = null, string strPar2 = null)
{
    var finalCode = @"
    public class Function
    {
      public string Main()
      { 
        string strPar1 = ****;
        string strPar2 = ***;
         **
      }
     }";
    if (strPar1 != null)
        finalCode = finalCode.Replace("****", strPar1);
    else
        finalCode = finalCode.Replace("****", "String.Empty");
    if (strPar2 != null)
        finalCode = finalCode.Replace("***", strPar2);
    else
        finalCode = finalCode.Replace("***", "String.Empty");
    finalCode = finalCode.Replace("**", strCode);

    var options = new CompilerParameters();
    options.GenerateExecutable = false;
    options.GenerateInMemory = false;

    var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
    var compile = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(options, finalCode);

    var type = compile.CompiledAssembly.GetType("Function");
    var abc = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

    var method = type.GetMethod("Main");
    var result = method.Invoke(abc, null);

    return result.ToString();

}
```

so you can see that I replace the first parameter, the second and the external code.

I call the function with

> var function = Helper.CreateCSharpFunction(strCode, "AAAA");

so strPar1 = "AAAA" and strPar2 = String.Empty.

While the external code from file is:

```
string strResult = strPar1 + "ABC";
return strResult;
```

If I check the result seems correct

[image]

but when I launch it I get this error

[image]

which translated is:
The following file or assembly could not be found: ...
and the name of the file changes every time

Thanks for any help
Patrick

Answer (score 0):

I feel sooooooo ashamed for not having come to this before. I was missing the " in strPar1. In my defence I can say that the error was very misleading
[image]

in my defence I can say that the error